# a bytes-like object is required not 'str'

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to create a local HTTP server for Flask.

Server starts successfully but when i try to run the **localhost:5000** in web browser i get this error

---

```
class webserverhandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

def do_GET(self):
    try:
        if self.path.endswith("/"):
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Content-Type','text/html')
            self.end_headers()

            output=""
            output+="<html><body>Hello</body></html>"

            self.wfile.write(output)
            print (output)
            return

    except IOError:
        self.send_error(404,"File Not Found %s" % self.path)


def main():
try:
    port=5000
    server=HTTPServer(('',port),webserverhandler)
    print ("webserver running on %s" % port)
    server.serve_forever()


except KeyboardInterrupt:
    server.socket.close()
```

----------------------------------ERROR-----------------------------------------

```
webserver running on 5000
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Feb/2017 17:59:36] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 54027)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Jordan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 317, in _handle_request_noblock
 self.process_request(request, client_address)
File "C:\Users\Jordan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 348, in process_request
 self.finish_request(request, client_address)
File "C:\Users\Jordan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 361, in finish_request
 self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
File "C:\Users\Jordan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 696, in __init__
 self.handle()
File "C:\Users\Jordan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\server.py", line 418, in handle
 self.handle_one_request()
File "C:\Users\Jordan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\server.py", line 406, in handle_one_request
method()
File "webserver.py", line 14, in do_GET
 self.wfile.write(output)
File "C:\Users\Jordan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 775, in write
 self._sock.sendall(b)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

---

anyone can help me?

Comment: Did you tried `self.wfile.write(output.encode())` ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can encode your `output` variable into a `bytes_object` like this:

```
self.wfile.write(output.encode())
```

Comment: This does not solve my problem. The answer below works fine.

Comment: @JamesChang This means you've another kind of problem not the actual OP problem.

Comment: This works but it is such a pain and waste of space. It should be obvious when to encode to binary. Makes for unreadable code.

Answer (score 5):

It seems you are using Python3, where string literals are unicode (`str`) objects by default. Use the `b`-prefix

```
output = b""
output += b"<html><body>Hello</body></html>"
```

to create a `bytes`-object.